# Check if two keys have the same value inside a map function in React

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to check if the data I am getting from a report object has the same values under a certain key, so that I can build a chart with different labels of only one for each value I get.
So far this is the code:

```
return (
<ChartDiv>
  <Bar
    data={{
      labels: [
        props.salesReports.map((label, i) => {
          //Check if I receive two of the same values
          return props.salesReports[i][4];
        }),
      ],
      datasets: [
        {
.......
```

Does anyone know if this is possible to do directly inside .map() or if the data needs to be polished beforehand?
Thanks!

Comment: can you show representation of your salesReports data??

Comment: Sure, it would look like this when I receive it.
SalesReports: Array (3088)
0 ["Provider", "Provider Country", "SKU", "Developer", "Title", "Version", "Product Type Identifier", "Units", "Developer Proceeds", "Begin Date", …] (28)
1 ["APPLE", "US", "some string", "Some Company", "Some product", "2.1", "7", "some version", "0.00", "some date", …] (28)
etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this example can help you

```js
let array = ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'B'];

let unique = array.filter((x, index) => array.indexOf(x) === index);

let duplicated = array.filter((x, index) => array.indexOf(x) !== index);

console.log("unique : " + unique); //[ 'A', 'B', 'C' ]

console.log("duplicated : " + duplicated ); //[ 'A', 'B' ]
```